# Determine local culture of a PC without creating an application

Tags: .net, localization, culture, cultureinfo

Is there any way to determine the local culture of a PC (such as en-US) without running an application?  I tried looking in Control Panel | Regional Settings (running WinXP), but I don't know how the choices there map to the PC's culture.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require creating an .exe, such as running a command from the command prompt (not PowerShell), or a VbScript or JS file (as long as we are getting the real culture and not IE settings.)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To view the information from the explorer interface follow the instructions in the other answers.

For the internal details, read on:

The locale is save per user under `HKCU\Control Panel\International\` under the value `LocaleName`

To quickly view your locale run this from the command line:

```
REG QUERY "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "LocaleName"
```

obviously you can query this information any way you like (cmd, powershell, vbs, c# etc...)

Comment: +1: HKCU for the current user's regional settings.  HKEY_USERS\.Default\Control Panel\International for the default regional settings (used by e.g. the SYSTEM account, or as the default for new users).  My machine (XP SP3) does not have a LocaleName value - there is a Locale value with the locale id.  Are you using Vista?

Comment: Thanks Y:  On XP, I can look at the 'Locale' value under HKCU\Control Panel\International\.   It is a Hex representation of the culture's LCID.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the System Information tool under Accessories->System it tells you locale in there.

Comment: System Information says I'm in Brazil, but my culture is en-US according to Yona's answer.