# DateTime funny time values

Tags: c#

I am using DateTime.Now.ToString() to show the present time in an application. It appears fine in some computers, but in other computers, the time shows funny values. 
For example, it shows 2010/11/09\0؎鶡撗䄠ϗ퉌؎鵢
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What are some of the 'funny' values that it shows?

Comment: what are funny values you are getting

Comment: How are you diagnosing this (where are you seeing the results) and what's the culture of those machines?

Comment: The funny values are like 2010/11/09\0؎鶡撗䄠ϗ퉌؎鵢. Instead of showing the time after the data, I get some funny values.

Comment: For checking the culture of the machines, I used this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863826/determine-local-culture-of-a-pc-without-creating-an-application  and it returned an error. Error: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the machine's date format. It should be of the same format which supports the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a format when converting:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Note that this format is ambiguous, as it uses a 12 hour clock but no am/pm designator.

Comment: if he wants 24 hours then he can edit it like "... H:mm:ss". I wrote this answer to show an "example"

Comment: The trouble is that when you give an example with a problem (ambiguity), but don't mention the problem, others are likely to use the code without even realizing there *is* a problem. (I'd usually go for `HH` rather than `h` personally.)

Comment: Ok. I will consider it next time. Thank you for caring about others.

Answer (score 1):

its not funny .. go to control panel and change `Regional and Language Options settings` .. and try again

or use culture info

Comment: I checked the Regional and Language Options settings. It is set to US.

Comment: check your clock on right corner what date-time its display ?